# How to display bigger colorbar/colorscale than I actually need in Python and plotly?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, heatmap

I have a heatmap with values between 0 and 90. However, I want to display a colorscale that has more intervals than my actual dataset(the dataset changes every month). I need different colors for intervals like: 0-50,51-100,101-150,151-200,201-300,301-500. How can I display different these different colors in colorscale with Plotly and Python? So far, I have this, which creates a colorbar that doesn't respect the intervals given. It divides my data(0-90 values) into 7 colors, even though the values aren't mapped to the given colors.

```
def discrete_colorscale(bvals, colors):
    """
    bvals - list of values bounding intervals/ranges of interest
    colors - list of rgb or hex colorcodes for values in [bvals[k], bvals[k+1]],0<=k < len(bvals)-1
    returns the plotly  discrete colorscale
    """
    if len(bvals) != len(colors) + 1:
        raise ValueError('len(boundary values) should be equal to  len(colors)+1')
    bvals = sorted(bvals)
    nvals = [(v - bvals[0]) / (bvals[-1] - bvals[0]) for v in bvals]  # normalized values

    dcolorscale = []  # discrete colorscale
    for k in range(len(colors)):
        dcolorscale.extend([[nvals[k], colors[k]], [nvals[k + 1], colors[k]]])
    return dcolorscale


bvals = [2, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 500]
colors = ['#0e7a04', '#f3ff2c', '#df8719', '#df8719','#641b6d','#810808']
dcolorsc = discrete_colorscale(bvals, colors)

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(y=['0', '1'], z=z_values, annotation_text=z_text, colorscale=dcolorsc)
```